# Scroll the page, then begin to scroll a div inside another div and then the page again. How

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to find the right jquery or js plugin to create an effect like this:

I have a long screen capture from a smartphone, is a huge image.
I want to put this image inside a scrolling div placed on top of a smartphone background image to simulate the screen.

I cannot find a way to manage the scrolling: I want to place this image in the middle of the page, and when the user scroll to the "smartphone" the windows scroll stop and my captured image placed inside the vertical scrolling div begin to scroll. At the end the page start to scroll again.

Is there something i can use?

Comment: Hey, can you insert your current code into the post?  It would help a lot in understanding the goal.

Comment: btw, what else do you have on the page, aside of image?
maybe you should think about positioning the rest

Comment: did you try hammerjs?

Comment: oops you might want to do that with repeating background image scrolling.

Comment: Here is the pen https://codepen.io/robypez/pen/LOjrPr